# Automated Stack usage analyser

Tags: c, stack

I just wanted to know that there is any free stack usage analyzer for C, something like http://www.absint.com/stackanalyzer/index.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that gprof is a good tool.

http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html

Comment: Thank you for answering. gprof is a free tool. But can it analyse stack usage?

Comment: @Hari It is not a graphic tool, but you can see your call stack during execution.  What exactly do you want for it to do?